# How i can optimize .concat method in es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, concatenation, destructuring

How i can optimise a .contact method with ES6 features.
My line work good, but am learning ES6 , and a would like to get some good example to write this code with somes es6 features. (destructuring or other cool way)
Thank

**the line a need to optimise because i don't like are:**

```
const list_B = buttonsType.toolz.concat(buttonsType.layerz,buttonsType.categoryz,buttonsType.sheetz,buttonsType.actionz);//***line to optimize */
```

the context are:

```
const buttonsType = {// slots Names for interactive buttons editor
            toolz:['iconParentMode', 'move', 'pivot', 'scaleicon', 'skewicon', 'rotateicon', 'drawLine', 'sunNigth', 'lockAll', 'playPause',],
            layerz:[ 'gb0', 'gb1', 'gb2', 'gb3', 'gb4', 'gb5', 'gb6',],
            categoryz:[ 'All', 'Characteres', 'Rocks', 'Trees', 'Buildings', 'Grass', 'FurnitureINT', 'FurnitureEXT', 'Cliffs', 'Objets', 'Divers copie',],
            sheetz:[ 'SpriteSheets', 'TileSheets', 'Spines', 'Sprites',],
            actionz:[ 'iconRenderable', 'icon_PinGrid', 'icon_grid', 'saveIcon',],
        };
    //////// ┌------------------------------------------------------------------------------┐
    //////// CREATE BUTTONS GRAFICS INTERACTIONS
    ////////└------------------------------------------------------------------------------┘
        // make and store buttons Data's
        (function(){
            // how i can optimise for es6 and write proper this concat ?
           const list_B = buttonsType.toolz.concat(buttonsType.layerz,buttonsType.categoryz,buttonsType.sheetz,buttonsType.actionz);//***line to optimize */

           for (let [i,len] = [0,list_B.length]; i < len; i++) {
               const name = list_B[i];
               const slot = $PME.gui.skeleton.findSlot(name);
           };
        })();
```

**EDIT: SOLVED**

```
    (function(){
   const list_B = Object.entries(buttonsType);
   for (let [i,len] = [0,list_B.length]; i < len; i++) {
       const [type,list_name] = [list_B[i][0], list_B[i][1]];
       list_name.forEach(name => {
        buttonsSlots[name] = $PME.gui.skeleton.findSlot(name);
        buttonsSlots[name].type = type;
       });
   };
})();
```

Comment: What do you mean "optimize"? If you don't want to use `concat`, you could use two `for ... of ...` (one nested).

Comment: sorry English are not my native language, A mean more readable and optimise with es6 features.

Comment: Why do you have these arrays in the object in the first place? What do the keys signify?

Comment: am building a GUI with category editor https://imgbox.com/tcgyYqer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Object.entries`

```
let a = [];
Object.entries(buttonsType).forEach(item => {a = a.concat(item[1])});
```

Comment: Note that is an ECMAScript 2017 (ES8) feature as opposed to ES6

Comment: This code is definitely super well written and very readable. Thank a lot it work well.

Comment: <pre>  (function(){
       const list_B = Object.entries(buttonsType);
       for (let [i,len] = [0,list_B.length]; i < len; i++) {
           const [type,list_name] = [list_B[i][0], list_B[i][1]];
           list_name.forEach(name => {
            buttonsSlots[name] = $PME.gui.skeleton.findSlot(name);
            buttonsSlots[name].type = type;
           });
       };
    })();
<code>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if one can talk of optimization, but I would do this:

```
const list_B = Object.keys(buttonsType)
  .reduce((acc, key) => {
    return acc.concat(buttonsType[key]);
  },[]);
```

Iterate over the keys in buttonsType. Concat into the empty array of reduce every array inside buttonsType's keys

Comment: Notice that this does not guarantee the correct order of concatenation.

Comment: It could have the arrays from `buttonsType` in any order.

Comment: yes order not have importance, thank for this code its look nice